# Export phpMyAdmin problems

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

I have built a wordpress site on my local host through mamp and now want to export it to a live site. I believe I have to export the wordpress database from phpMyAdmin, but when I select my database and go to the export tab and push GO on the quick export method, I am taken to another screen and not the downloadable box that appears and it will no let me download the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost operating system is Linux, my advice to you is to export the database manually.

Type on the shell prompt while replacing what's inside the brackets with your own values :

```
mysqldump -u [your_username] -p[your_password] [wordpress_database_name] > /tmp/[wordpress_database_name].sql
```

This will export your database inside your /tmp/ folder in a file called wordpress_database_name.sql.

This command can also be used on Windows if you installed a MariaDB or MySQL server, which comes with all the utilities needed for export. All you have to do is to change your directory in the command prompt until you are inside your binary utilities directory (it's often something like "C:\Program Files\MariaDB\bin\"), and then type :

```
mysqldump.exe -u [your_username] -p[your_password] [wordpress_database_name] > [wordpress_database_name].sql
```

It will do the same as the shell command before but in the "bin" directory.

Don't hesitate if you need something to be explained again.